# Algorithm to find minimal subsets of a set to fullfill conditions

Tags: algorithm

I want to extract the minimum number of rows of a dataframe to cover all elements of some columns.
Here is the example :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTcMv.png)

condition:
new dataframe's checklist1 cover (a, b,c); new dataframe's checklist2 cover (alpha, beta, delta, gamma) ; new dataframe's project_id cover (proj1, proj2,proj3) ;

solution:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s6jx.png)

I tried to solve this problem with enumeration. Finally, I gave up this method for lots of calculations.

Comment: This is a variation of the well known [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). No surprise that the number of calculations is high, since this is a NP-complete problem.

Comment: @m.raynal, for my problem,  do you have any algorithm to suggestion?

Comment: @wikichung Not sure you understood m.raynal's answer. To make it clear:  There is NO efficient algorithm for your problem. You can find an approximate (good but not perfect) answer using a greedy algorithm described in the wiki that he linked.

Comment: how many rows are there in the dataframe? If the number is very small, like the one in the example (or even slightly larger, e.g. 20 rows), you can just iterate through all subsets of rows, and retain the smallest such subset that satisfies the requirement.

Comment: @qwertyman Thank you. I have solved the problem using greedy algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is a variation of the well known [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).
Since this problem is NP-complete, finding an optimal solution (meaning the smallest amount of element, in your case rows, that will cover all values) can take a huge amount of time if the input is not really small. Said otherwise, the complexity of this problem is exponential with regards to the input size (`O(2^n)`, with `n` the number of rows, more or less).

But don't lose hope, there are methods that will allow you to find an optimal solution if the input is small, or a very satisfying approximation if your input is quite big. By small input, I mean an number of row in the order of magnitude of 100, more or less.

[Branch and bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound): This algorithm is more or less a 'clever' way to brute force, it runs much, much faster than a brute force algorithm. It can find an optimal solution (given enough time, and if the input is big, enough time might mean a million years), or it can be stopped and return the best solution found so far. I don't advice you to go for this method, but you should definitely read about it, it is a very efficient and versatile algorithm, a must-know.

[Integer Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming): That is the best way, imho, to tackle this problem. The ILP allows you to write your program as a integer linear program, and then to feed it to an ILP solver (there are many on the market, free or not, you can find a list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_optimization_software)). If you never heard about linear programming, you can have a look [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-053-optimization-methods-in-management-science-spring-2013/tutorials/MIT15_053S13_tut01.pdf) for some explanations.
This method has two BIG advantages:

- Writing an ILP program that would solve the set cover problem is very easy, as you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Integer_linear_program_formulation) (a dozen lines at most).
- ILP solvers are very, ..., very optimized, they have been written specifically to tackle this kind of problem. If your input is less than, say a 1000 rows, it should find an optimal solution. And, in any case, it will find a better solution than almost any program. At least, a better solution than a program you'd spend less than a week writing.

There is always the possibility to go for a greedy algorithm, but the set cover problem cannot be approximated by a polynomial time algorithm (this is an over-simplification of the truth, but sufficient in our case, we want to solve a instance of set cover, not prove P=NP or work on the unique games conjecture). So the results of a greedy algorithm can be infinitely worse than an optimal solution. And will run only slighty faster than an incredibly better ILP solver.